# I'm trying to fetch a value produced by JS using Watir, but failing

Tags: watir, watir-webdriver

(Warning: this link is SFW, but the site hosts NSFW text/audio content on other pages, so maybe don't click through on a work computer.)

I am trying to access a series of pages [like this](https://soundgasm.net/u/tarkustrooper/F-Levon-Elton-John-cover). Each page streams an M4A audio file. Once the page loads, the jQuery document-ready event goes and fetches the duration of the audio and puts it on the page.

That's the value I want, the contents of `div.jp-duration` after the JavaScript has done its insertion.

To do this, I am writing

```
headless = Headless.new
headless.start
browser = Watir::Browser.start "https://soundgasm.net/u/tarkustrooper/F-Wasted-Time-The-Eagles"
duration = browser.execute_script %q{return $("div.jp-duration").innerHTML}
```

but I'm not returned anything.

If I try `$("#jquery_jplayer_1").data('jPlayer').status.duration`, expecting the number of seconds, I get back 0, even though this works if I try in a Chrome console.

I'm using Watir wrong somehow, but I don't knowit well enough to know how. I'd love some help if possible.

I'm using Ruby 2.1.5, Watir 5.0.0, Watir-Webdriver 0.8.0 and Headless 2.2.0 on CentOS 6.

Answer (score 0):

This should work without the need for execute_script:
`@browser.div(class: 'jp-duration').text`